# Website access denied using puppeteer on cloud functions

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, google-cloud-functions, puppeteer, google-chrome-headless

I am trying to scape this url https://www.myntra.com/laptop-bag/chumbak/chumbak-unisex-brown-geo-bird--printed-laptop-bag/6795882/buy using puppeteer.
It's working when i use `{ headless: false }`, but failing in headless mode.

Then i have compared response in both cases using this.

```
const resp = await page.goto(url);
console.log(resp);
```

Then i figured out that we need to add userAgent when using headless mode. so i have added this.

```
await page.setUserAgent('Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36');
```

Now it is working in both cases **locally**. But when i deploy to cloud function, it is still failing.

This is the screenshot taken using puppeteer.
[image]

this is some part of the response log.

```
_headers: 
   { status: '403',
     server: 'AkamaiGHost',
     'mime-version': '1.0',
     'content-type': 'text/html',
     'content-length': '395',
     expires: 'Thu, 09 Jul 2020 12:16:30 GMT',
     date: 'Thu, 09 Jul 2020 12:16:30 GMT',
     'set-cookie': 'AKA_A2=A; expires=Thu, 09-Jul-2020 13:16:30 GMT........
```

Am i missing anything?

Thanks.

**update:**

I have used puppeteer stealth plugin along with IP rotation. here is the code

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer-extra');

const StealthPlugin = require('puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth')
puppeteer.use(StealthPlugin())

const AdblockerPlugin = require('puppeteer-extra-plugin-adblocker')
puppeteer.use(AdblockerPlugin({ blockTrackers: true }))
```

And for IP rotation:

```
var browser = await puppeteer.launch({
           headless: true,
           args: ['--proxy-server=abcd-efg.proxymesh.com:12345']
         });

var page = await browser.newPage();

await page.setUserAgent('Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36');

await page.authenticate({
          username: 'myusername',
          password: 'mypassword'
        });
```

IP rotation working locally but still blocked on cloud function.

Comment: The IP and headless footprint is probably banned in that Akamai. You have to use stealth and other bypassing technologies.

Comment: @Md.AbuTaher I just now tried using [puppeteer-extra](https://github.com/berstend/puppeteer-extra/tree/master/packages/puppeteer-extra) but still not working on cloud function.

Comment: Did you try with puppeteer stealth plugin with some dedicated proxies?

Comment: @Md.AbuTaher yes, i tried it with [ProxyMesh](https://proxymesh.com/) now. IP rotation working locally but still same error in cloud function.

Comment: Share your code with stealth.

Comment: @Md.AbuTaher updated

Comment: Why do you want to run the script in cloud function? Why not in a VM?

Comment: @bigbounty I want to make use of the serverless environment for my asynchronous requests which will scale quickly in response to demand.

Comment: If the stealth and proxies are not working, then you need to compare the request headers for the two instances, local and cloud function. It could be that the cloud function is not sending the same headers.

Comment: @Tom It is having same headers, I have tried the same implementation in AWS lambda aswell , still getting the same issue. do we need to enable request interception?

Comment: Tom,  @Md.AbuTaher I have used proxymesh which doesn't have access to residential proxies, using residential proxies works?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Using residential proxies fixed the issue.**

Initially I have deployed in cloud function and AWS lambda with IP rotation. I have used proxymesh service for IP rotation. but it provides data center proxies only. It was failed. Then i tried with residential proxies from another service. It worked.

Comment: which service do you use?

Comment: @daniel I am using BlazingSEO service. if you need bulk IPs I heard luminati is best.